# How to implement a SSL server on Windows CE

Tags: ssl, windows-ce

I need to implement a server running on Windows CE 5.0 that shall communicate on a secure connection. To implement a secure connection SSL looks like a good choice.

The Windows CE 5.0 Winsock implementation allows to implement all the SLL stuff using the [Winsock Secure Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886618.aspx). But the problem is that the referred site states:

SSL does not support the following Winsock functionality ... "Calls to the `accept` function".

How can I implement a SSL secured server when `accept` will not work? What other options do I have to implement a secure connection to a Windows CE 5.0 device?

*Edit:* My current application implementation is in C++. So I would prefer an approach that use the Windows API or a C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

We ported the [Mentalis Secure Socket Library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/ssocket/) to the Compact Framework for when we needed SSL.  It was fairly painless, though not without its bugs.

Comment: Mentalis stuff is dead as a log and with recent findings in SSL vulnerabilities it's a good idea to have modern TLS versions support (and this is not possible with mentalis).

Comment: I totally agree that TLS would be nice, but good luck finding anything even recently new with Windows CE support.  I'm not even certain the OS he's using would support it.

Comment: Our SecureBlackbox does ;)

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp SecureBlockbox doesn't since it's C++ edition supports only x86 and x64. There are other CPUs supported in Windows CE.

Comment: @harper It is possible to compile C++ edition of SecureBlackbox for Windows CE, I think, so this can be done as a custom service.

Answer (score 0):

[MatrixSSL](http://www.matrixssl.org/) supports Windows CE:

> MatrixSSL™ is an embedded **SSL and TLS** implementation designed for
>   small footprint applications and devices. Available is a fully
>   supported, commercial version as well as an open source version that
>   is available for download. MatrixSSL allows secure management of
>   remote devices. Several secure embedded Web servers also use MatrixSSL
>   for their encryption layer.
>
> MatrixSSL has been ported to operating systems including
>   FreeRTOS, Bare Metal, eCos, VxWorks, uClinux, eCos, FreeRTOS, ThreadX,
>   **WindowsCE**, PocketPC, Palm, pSOS, SMX, BREW, MacOS X, Linux and
>   Windows.